# How do I fix the incorrect file path in my mounted drive in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have mounted my drive on Google Colab and have the file I want to read in exactly next to my notebook stored. Still it gives me the incorrect filepath error, however I am very certain there's no mistake.

[Code + Filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgEIn.png)

Loading excel data into a variable in python through a mounted google drive file

Comment: The path is not relative to the folder containing the source, it's relative to the "working directory" of your process.  `print(os.getcwd())` to see what that directory is.

Comment: Thank you correct filepath is then: 
data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Data/GDP_Data_Extract_World_Bank.xls')

Comment: That's another way to solve it.